# Paypal Buy Now IPN returning empty item_number in POST vars

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

The problem in short - Paypal is returning the POST var item_number but it is blank.

Details:

- Customer hits Buy Now and is taken over to Paypal where the transaction is completed and then they are sent back to my site.
- I use a notification url/page to update the database, but it relies on an item_number to trigger the proper code.
- I know there was recently a change to item_number1 or item_number_1 that I've seen referenced in some other questions but I'm printing all POST vars to a temporary file (via php in the notification url) and all I see is item_number and it is blank.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated as I'm no Paypal expert and I've been banging my head against the wall trying to figure out why it's not sending me back a value.  Some code snippets and useful stuff below...(note i've modified some of the values for security, but nothing else)

**My "Buy Now" Link** = https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=MYBUTTONID&lc=US&page_style=primary&item_number=PayPerCard&invoice=00000000&custom=userName

**Loop for printing POST vars**

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
$data.= $key.'='.$value.'\n';}
```

$data is just printed into a temp file every time a transaction is completed

**$data =**

```
transaction_subject=
payment_date=17:25:25 Oct 16, 2017 PDT
txn_type=web_accept
last_name=McDougal
receipt_id=0000-0000-0000-0000
residence_country=US
item_name=Buy & Send
payment_gross=1.50
mc_currency=USD
business=sales@mydomain.com
payment_type=instant
protection_eligibility=Ineligible
verify_sign=BIGLONGSTRING
payer_status=unverified
payer_email=customer@gmail.com
txn_id=BIGLONGSTRING
quantity=1
receiver_email=sales@mydomain.com
first_name=Sticky
invoice=00000000
payer_id=0000000000000
receiver_id=0000000000000
item_number=
payment_status=Completed
payment_fee=0.37
mc_fee=0.37
mc_gross=1.50
custom=userName
charset=windows-1252
notify_version=3.8
ipn_track_id=0000000000000
```

Answer (score 0):

So of course after spending hours hunting and debugging and finally posting to stackoverflow, I figured out the problem ten minutes later and it was a super easy fix.  Posting here on the off chance someone else can benefit.

SOLUTION : Not sure when it happened, but Paypal uses a field labeled as "Item ID" when you create a hosted button.  This is the item_number and it must be set here, not in the Buy Now link as I previously had it.

[image of PayPal fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D78mR.png)

Setting that field to my desired item_number did the trick.